Common allow-list for audit-ci, trivy and Dependabot
I have a Node.js application deployed as Docker container. When it comes to checking for known vulnerabilities, that happens at three places:

In a pre-merge check via a wrapper around npm audit called audit-ci. There you can allow-list vulnerabilities in a command line argument like --allowlist GHSA...
After building the docker image and right before deploying it, we check the image with trivy. In trivy, you can allowlist vulnerabilities in a .trivyignore file in the CVE-2024- format.
Dependabot runs on the repo. In Dependabot you can "Dismiss alert" via the GitHub GUI.

When a new vulnerability gets into the NPM advisory, updating the dependency is the preferred way. But it happens quite often that you cannot update the package in question and at the same time I think I can ignore the vulnerability. Now, it is quite tedious to "allow-list" the vulnerability in three different places in two different notations (GHSA... vs CVE-.)
What's the best way of solving that?
Preferable I would have one file in the code, listing all allowed vulnerabilities in one notation, with the option to add a human-readable comment on why I think I can ignore the vulnerability in question (ideally you would even be forced to add such a comment).
